# How to post or pass data to SIP request?

Tags: ios, sip

How do we post request or pass parameter to SIP server in iOS? Is it through header or XML? 
When i researched it is saying the SIP request is similar to HTTP. Can this be done through REST API?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP, MAIL and SIP formats are similar: they all contain "method", "headers" and "bodies". But they all require different implementations.

With MAIL, you can provide URIs with parameters which can be used to prepare email:

```
mailto:john@domain.com?Subject=Hello
```

And a MAIL program, will prepare a MAIL to john@domain.com with the *Subject: Hello*.

With SIP, the same can be done:

```
sip:john@domain.com;method=INVITE?Subject=Hello&X-Info=About%20SIP
```

A stack receiving this URI should make a call to sip:john@domain.com with
the following INVITE:

```
INVITE sip:john@domain.com SIP/2.0
Subject: Hello
X-Info: About SIP
To: sip:john@domain.com
-and all usual headers-
```

Here is an example with osip2/eXosip2:

```
eXosip_message_build_request (&msg,
      "MESSAGE",
      "<sip:caller@sip.antisip.com?Subject=Hello&X-Info=About%20SIP>", 
      "sip:caller@sip.antisip.com",
      "sip:sip.antisip.com");
```

There are many sip stacks running on iOS. They are mostly written in C and I guess you'll need to use one of them.